# Amazon Product Advertising API signed request with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, web-services, amazon-product-advertising-api

After many hours of tinkering and reading the whole internet several times I just can't figure out how to sign requests for use with the Product Advertising API.

So far I managed to generate a client from the provided WSDL file. I used a tutorial by Amazon for this. You can find it here:

[Tutorial for generating the web service client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/index.html?YourDevelopmentEnvironment.html)

So far no problems. To test the client I wrote a small piece of code. The code is intended to simply get some information about a product. The product is specified by its ASIN.

The code:

```
package client;

import com.ECS.client.jax.AWSECommerceService;
import com.ECS.client.jax.AWSECommerceServicePortType;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemLookup;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemLookupResponse;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemLookupRequest;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("API Test startet");
    
    AWSECommerceService service = new AWSECommerceService();
    AWSECommerceServicePortType port = service.getAWSECommerceServicePort();
    
    ItemLookupRequest itemLookup = new ItemLookupRequest();
    itemLookup.setIdType("ASIN");
    itemLookup.getItemId().add("B000RE216U");
    
    ItemLookup lookup = new ItemLookup();
    lookup.setAWSAccessKeyId("<mykeyishere>");
    lookup.getRequest().add(itemLookup);
    
    ItemLookupResponse response = port.itemLookup(lookup);
    
    String r = response.toString();
    System.out.println("response: " + r);
    
    System.out.println("API Test stopped");
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no part where I sign the request. I have worked my way through a lot of the classes used and found no methods for signing the request.

So, how to sign a request?

I actually found something in the documentation: [request authentication](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-11-01/DG/)

But they don't use their own API. The proposed solutions are more or less for manual use only. So I looked in the client classes to sort out if I could get the request URL and put all the parts needed for request signing in myself. But there are no such methods.

I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

---

This is what I did to solve the problem. All the credit goes to [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84539/jon) and the guys of the Amazon forums.

Before I outline what I did, here is a link to the post which helped me to solve the problem: [Forum Post on Amazon forums](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=143124).

I downloaded the awshandlerresolver.java which is linked in the post. Than I modified my own code so it looks like this:

```
package client;

import com.ECS.client.jax.AWSECommerceService;
import com.ECS.client.jax.AWSECommerceServicePortType;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemLookup;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemLookupResponse;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemLookupRequest;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("API Test startet");
    
    AWSECommerceService service = new AWSECommerceService();
    service.setHandlerResolver(new AwsHandlerResolver("<Secret Key>"));  // important
    AWSECommerceServicePortType port = service.getAWSECommerceServicePort();
    
    ItemLookupRequest itemLookup = new ItemLookupRequest();
    itemLookup.setIdType("ASIN");
    itemLookup.getItemId().add("B000RE216U");

    ItemLookup lookup = new ItemLookup();
    lookup.setAWSAccessKeyId("<Access Key>"); // important
    lookup.getRequest().add(itemLookup);

    ItemLookupResponse response = port.itemLookup(lookup);

    String r = response.toString();
    System.out.println("response: " + r);   
    System.out.println("API Test stopped");
  }
}
```

The `println` on the end are more or less useless. But it works. I also used the WSDL Jon linked to generate a new webservice client. I just changed the URLs in the tutorial I posted in my question.

Comment: thanks for posting this summary, just saved me about a day's effort!

Comment: another thing: the [client-side API generation notes](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/YourDevelopmentEnvironment.html) don't make it explicit that the developer **must** input the jaxws-custom.xml file to wsimport , or examples such as Jens' won't compile with the code it generates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this afer you create the service

```
service.setHandlerResolver(new AwsHandlerResolver(my_AWS_SECRET_KEY));
```

You'll need [this](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/servlet/JiveServlet/download/53-35999-143146-2680/awshandlerresolver.java) class and [this](http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi) jar file to add as a reference to your project as AwsHandlerResolver uses Base64 encoding.

You'll need to rename the AwsHandlerResolver file to the name of the class as the file name is all lower case.

I think the rest of the code you have is fine.

The WSDL is http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

Comment: The WSDL is from April 2010. So its fairly new. Do you use the sample code from google? I once found something there which actually looked very much like what you have. The client generated from the by Amazon provided WSDL didn't include a class like AwsHandlerResolver. But thank you for your suggestions anyways!

Comment: Your answer was great. The linked post on the Amazon forums helped me a lot! I edited my post to incorporate your answer. Thank you very much Jon.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I just tried it and I get null response but same code on Mac gets result.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion and the related Amazon post helped me get the client working. That being said, I felt that the solution could be improved with regards to the following:

1. Setting WebService handlers in code is discouraged. A XML configuration file and a corresponding @HandlerChain annotation are recommended.
2. A SOAPHandler is not required in this case, LogicalHandler would do just fine. A SOAPHandler has more reach than a LogicalHandler and when it comes to code, more access is not always good.
3. Stuffing the signature generation, addition of a Node and printing the request in one handler seems like a little too much. These could be separated out for separation of responsibility and ease of testing. One approach would be to add the Node using a XSLT transformation so that the handler could remain oblivious of the transformation logic. Another handler could then be chained which just prints the request. 
   [Example](http://www.mediafire.com/?9rdhn1r8na19mft)

Answer (score -2):

i did this in spring it's working fine.

```
package com.bookbub.application;


import com.ECS.client.jax.*;
import com.ECS.client.jax.ItemSearch;

import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClient {

private static final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "AI*****2Y7Z****DIHQ";
private static final String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "lIm*****dJuiy***YA+g/vnj/Ix*****Oeu";
private static final String ASSOCIATE_TAG = "****-**";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClient ist = new TestClient();
    ist.runSearch();
}

public void runSearch()
{
    AWSECommerceService service = new AWSECommerceService();
    service.setHandlerResolver(new AwsHandlerResolver(AWS_SECRET_KEY));
    AWSECommerceServicePortType port = service.getAWSECommerceServicePort();

    ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();
    request.setSearchIndex("Books");
    request.setKeywords("java web services up and running oreilly");

    ItemSearch search = new ItemSearch();
    search.getRequest().add(request);
    search.setAWSAccessKeyId(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);

    Holder<OperationRequest> operation_request =null;
    Holder<List<Items>> items = new Holder<List<Items>>();

    port.itemSearch(
            search.getMarketplaceDomain(),
            search.getAWSAccessKeyId(),
            search.getAssociateTag(),
            search.getXMLEscaping(),
            search.getValidate(),
            search.getShared(),
            search.getRequest(),
            operation_request,
            items);

    java.util.List<Items> result = items.value;
    BigInteger totalPages = result.get(0).getTotalResults();
    System.out.println(totalPages);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.get(0).getItem().size(); ++i)
    {   Item myItem = result.get(0).getItem().get(i);
        System.out.print(myItem.getASIN());
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.println(myItem.getDetailPageURL());
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.println(myItem.getSmallImage() == null ? "" : myItem.getSmallImage().getURL());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to state what the code does, instead of just pasting the code

Answer (score -3):

You could achieve the same monetization outcomes with the IntentBrite API as well