# Where to put affiliate id in amazon product advertising api call in java

Tags: java, api, amazon-product-api

I'm still very new to programming and I decided to try to integrate someone else's api call in a Gui project I'm doing in Java.  The project is a really simple music search utility, where you can search for a band and find album art or lyrics etc.  I found some code that seems to work but it's missing the affiliate id.  I couldn't figure out where I should be putting this.  I'm hoping this will help others like me who are biting off more than they can chew, in the hopes that we'll get something out of working with code that's over our heads.  Sorry if that's not the case.  Anyways, I got the code from this post
[Amazon Product Advertising API through Java/SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336427/amazon-product-advertising-api-through-java-soap)
it seems to work but I'm getting bad creds type errors.  In the console, I'm seeing this "Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include AssociateTag."  The code I used was basically copy/paste from Jonathan Spooner.  If anyone has any idea where Amazon's product advertising api needs an affiliate id param or where I can look, aside from Amazon's docs because I couldn't find it there, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*AssociateTag* is mandatory parameter since version *2011-08-01*.

If you use Johnatan's code, from the link you provided, basically you have to put *AssociateTag* in the parameters map:

```
params.put("AssociateTag", your-affiliate-id);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm sorry that took so long to recognize that it helped.  I just learned why reputation points are nice so i'll do my best to give them, when my puny 4 points allows it.  Thanks for your help, good sir.